# Allow only one host to connect using ingress nginx configmap

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I can see that nginx has an option to allow and deny. I can allow host.domain.com and deny all using nginx see: https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/blocking-allowing-ip-addresses-in-nginx/.

However, how can I describe that in the ConfigMap for the ingress? I see the block-cidrs option in the doc https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/. An example ConfigMap would be very helpful. Or should this be done by using a nginx template?

Comment: could whitelist-source-range be what I have missed? If so I will post an example ConfigMap.yaml

Comment: I have found another example that should useful on top of using the whitelist-source-range option in this article https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/examples/auth/client-certs/ingress.yaml

Comment: I can't find the solution in link could you provide explanation or explain what help you?